# sed search and show matching pattern, removing the rest

Tags: sed, package-management, rpm

I am trying to clean a list containing packages. I wish to remove the package revisions, leaving the package names only.

I see every package has naming convention like this: package-name-majorver-minorver , etc: openssl-1.0.1e-57.0.5.el6 . I want openssl only, not -1.0.1e-57.0.5.el6

So far I have this `sed 's/^.*-//'`, but this doesn't work obviously.

Comment: watch out for package names with dashes! If you're gathering the list with RPM, consider using the --queryformat to get the %NAME separately.

Answer (score 1):

If the package name always has two version number parts appended, separated by hyphens, and if the version parts never contain a hyphen, you can use this command

```
sed 's/-[^-]*-[^-]*$//'
```

This will remove two hyphens, each followed by 0 or more non-hyphen characters, at the end of the line (`$`). It would also change e.g. `foo-bar-baz--` to `foo-bar-baz`.

Answer (score 0):

If the package name doesn't contain `-`, this should work:

```
sed -r 's/([^-]+).*/\1/'
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does, and the number of - 's are inconsistent too, eg: tmux and python-pip, the only consistent ones are major ver and minor ver appended to back separated by -

Answer (score 0):

Well I know it's not the best solution, but I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153277/5227747, so the solution was

```
cat file | sed 's/ // ; s/-/\t/' | rev | cut -f 3- | rev | sed 's/\t/-/'
```

it removes the last two '-'-separated columns without fuss, if anyone knows how to do it better I would love to know.

Comment: Unneccessary `cat`

Comment: I have to read from a file. I will check sed to improve the command

Comment: You should almost always do `sed ... file` instead of `cat file | sed ...`